# Can I run Lubuntu 18.10 and ubuntu 16.04 on two separate disks at the same time?

Tags: grub2

Would this corrupt GRUB in any of them? Currently, I disconnect one if I were to use the other, but can I keep them connected? Would GRUB recognize both of them?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can connect both the disks to the PC. Grub will add both by `sudo update-grub`. Of-course you can't **run** two OS at one time if that is what you meant by *"Can I run Lubuntu 18.10 and ubuntu 16.04 on two separate disks at the same time?"*

Answer (score 0):

GRUB is capable of dual-boot. Not just Ubuntu+Windows but Ubuntu+Ubuntu, too. (By Ubuntu I mean any Ubuntu flavour in this answer.)

You should just connect both the drives, boot and with both drives mounted in Ubuntu, run

```
sudo update-grub
```

It should detect both the systems and make you able to choose in the GRUB menu. However, you still cannot boot both systems at the same time, if you’re asking for that. This would require virtualization.